# Pandas groupBy two columns and keeping the columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
param1   param2   num1    num2
A          B        4      0.3
A          C        5      0.1
A          B        6      0.5
B          F        3      0.7
C          A        1      0.8
C          A        2      1.1
```

and I want something like

```
param1   param2   num1    num2
A          B        10     0.8
A          C        5      0.1
B          F        3      0.7
C          A        3      1.9
```

If I use something like:
`df.groupby(['param1', 'param2']).sum()`
I end up with the columns 'param1' and 'param2' fused as an index, but I don't want that. I just need them to stay as they are, but if I have some lines with the same param1 and param2, sum the 'nums' associated to them.

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['param1', 'param2'], as_index=False).sum()` or `df.groupby(['param1', 'param2']).sum().reset_index()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `as_index=False` parameter:

```
df.groupby(['param1', 'param2'], as_index=False).sum()`
```

Comment: Why answering for dupes?

Comment: because it takes me much more time to search for the potential duplicates, and that in fine, it will help OP better to just provide the answer

Comment: yes, but then it means need points, because not change to wiki, right?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean

Comment: Sure, do it if you want

Comment: ya, its happens answeing for dupes, but why need points for it? If dont need points wiki is best use here in my opinion. There is answer and not get points for 1000 times answered questions in dupes.

Comment: sorry, i imagined this question was already asked, but I couldn't find the answer; I probably didn't use the proper search terms

Comment: hmmm, so no wiki?

Comment: @jezrael i thought you did it, I told you you could. I'm also busy IRL ;)

Comment: @mozway - I cannot do it ;)